# "Recent Items" count is not saved in System Preferences-OS X 10.11 "El Capitan"

Tags: macos, system-settings

In System Preferences, when I try to change "Recent Items" count from "none" to any other value it is not saved. I can change it, but when I close System Preferences and open it again I still see "none" in "Recent Items". What can be the problem? Is there a way to change it manually? I am using OS X 10.11 "El Capitan".

[image]

Comment: By the way, if you want to take a screenshot of an individual window quickly, you use Cmd-Shift-4, like you always do, but next press the spacebar, and click on the window you want to take a screenshot of. It also looks better this way IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the .plist file is corrupted. Go to Library/Preferences and drag the file named com.apple.recentitems.plist into the Trash and empty it. When you open System Preferences again a new com.apple.recentitems.plist file will be created and you should be able to change the number of Recent Items without issue.

[image: com.apple.recentitems.plist in the Finder]

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work on my pc. what is the key inside the file? I may try change it manually. in current com.apple.recentitems.plist has only, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>"

Comment: it was not working. but after I restarted pc, it was working after than.